How to filter dates in cells that contain more data
We have a Google Sheet with all the workouts of a client:
Here is a test sheet
sheet 'History'
         A           B           C           D
    01/07/2024  02/07/2024  03/07/2024
1   WARMING-UP  WARMING-UP  WARMING-UP
    - exercise  - exercise  - exercise 

    01/08/2024  02/08/2024  03/08/2024
2   WARMING-UP  WARMING-UP  WARMING-UP
    - exercise  - exercise  - exercise 

    04/08/2024  05/08/2024  06/08/2024  07/08/2024
3   WARMING-UP  CANCELLED   WARMING-UP  WARMING-UP
    - exercise              - exercise  - exercise

    08/08/2024  09/08/2024  100/08/2024
4   WARMING-UP  WARMING-UP  CANCELLED
    - exercise  - exercise  

One training session in one cell with date and exercises. When clients cancel a session, the text "CANCELLED" is added instead of the exercises.
We are now looking for a way to use this data to create the correct invoice with how many sessions have been "CANCELLED" and how many not, within a given date range.
Desired result sessions cancelled:

Count: 2
"Dates: 05/08/2024, 10/08/2024"

Desired result sessions not cancelled:

Count: 8
"Dates: 01/08/2024 , 02/08/2024, 03/08/2024, 04/08/2024, 06/08/204, 07/08/2024, 08/08/2024, 09/082024"

In my attempts I can't seem to past the issue that all rows are counted, even without the start en end date filter:
=COUNTIFS(ARRAYFORMULA(DATEVALUE(LEFT(History!A2:Z91, SEARCH(CHAR(10), History!A2:Z91)-1))), ">="&DATEVALUE("28/08/2024"), ARRAYFORMULA(DATEVALUE(LEFT(History!A2:Z91, SEARCH(CHAR(10), History!A2:Z91)-1))), "<="&DATEVALUE("31/10/2024"))

Thank you for your help.

How tied are you to using the dd/mm/yyyy format in the History tab. I say this bcoz your sheet locale seems to use mm/dd/yyyy format & the formula would be a lot more flexible(without the additional date manipulation steps) if the locale format is used in History entries

@rockinfreakshow not so much, it can be changed, no problem. I just like the interface in the English language.

Create REGular EXpressions for matching date, and matching keywords and IF both MATCH, we EXTRACT the corresponding dates from the filtered range:
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  LET(
    dateRegex, "(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/08/2024",
    keyRegex, "CANCELLED", 
    rg, A1:D5,
    filteredData, TOCOL(
     IF(
       REGEXMATCH(rg,dateRegex)
       *REGEXMATCH(rg, keyRegex),
      rg,
     ),
    1),
    dates, REGEXEXTRACT(filteredData, dateRegex), 
    dates
  )
)


The only thing missing is a filter between start and end date

@DarkLite1 dateRegex can be used to limit the dates as needed. Try at https://regex101.com

I'm just trying to feed it 2 dates. My regex skills are useless to get to the correct one..
